# Umbraco user control database connectivity issue for user logging

Tags: .net, umbraco

I have developed a user login user control for Umbraco. I'm using a SQL server 2008 database.In the user control i have put a try catch block.So once i clicked on the login button it gives and Null value exception.This is my code.

```
        protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = TextBox1.Text;
        string password = TextBox2.Text;

        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            sc.Open();
            SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT email,passwd FROM umbUser");
            SqlDataReader sdr;
            sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                String uname = sdr.GetString(1);
                String pwd = sdr.GetString(2);

                if ((username.Equals(uname)) && (password.Equals(pwd)))
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = "Correct";
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = "Wrong";
                }
            }
            sc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e5)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "" + e5;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unusual that you want to re-write the existing .net membership providers and functionality to write your own from scratch. Why not use the existing membership functionality and just the standard .net controls. The code will be a lot more resilient than the solution you are trying to do with the code sample, which I'm sorry to say will be quite inefficient.

Have a look at this - http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers

Comment: If this answer is helpful I'd appreciate you marking this as an answer. If not - no worries